# Android SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory, editTable parameter

Tags: android

[SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQueryWithFactory%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) has one parameter `editTable` which I don't really understand. I looked at the source and found out that I'll probably be fine by using `findEditTables( tableName )` as the value (because that's the value which is used when `queryWithFactory` is called), and as `findEditTables` will just get the first table out of that string list, I guess simply passing one of the table names I am quering as the parameter will work out fine.

However that still doesn't help me to understand what the parameter is used for, so if you know it would be nice if you could explain :)

Answer (score 0):

> editTable --> SQLiteDirectCursorDriver --> SQLiteCursor

`SQLiteDirectCursorDriver` passes `editTable` to `SQLiteCursor` without affecting anything else.